# combine multiple useState of adding value into array into single function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This question is just related to reducing the code complexity. I have 8 arrays, in which I have to add items based on a button click. what I did is make 8 separate functions for all these tasks. is there any solution to combine all these functions into a single function that accepts an array as a parameter and does the rest of the job?

```
const [deleteArray,setDeleteArray]=useState([]);
const [newArray,setNewArray]=useState([]);
    const handleDeleteParking = (id) => {
        setDeleteArray((deleteArray) => [...deleteArray, id]);
}
   const handleNewParking = (id) => {
        setNewArray((newArray) => [...newArray, id]);
}
```

I have a total of 8 arrays with 8 separate functions to add items to the array, how can I achieve this task with a single function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pass the array into the function, since the array and the `setArray` function are different. But you can of course pass in the setter function instead:

```
const addToArray = (id, setStateFn) => {
    setStateFn((arr) => [...arr, id]);
}

// usage: instead of handleDeleteParking(id)
addToArray(id, setDeleteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have created an object that will store all your values.

Check the below code that may help you.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
   deleteParking: [],
   newParking: [],
});

const handleChange = (key, id) => {
   setData(prev => {
        return {
            ...prev,
            [key]: [
                ...prev[key],
                id,
            ]
        }
    });
}

handleChange('deleteParking', 1);
handleChange('newParking', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all of your state into one state and then you can create common function to update particular state and then along with array (updated array) you can pass the property name. Like this:

```
const [arrState,setArrayState]=useState({deleteArr:[]});
const commonUpdateFunction=(id, propertyName)=>{
    setArrayState (prev=> ({...prev,[propertyName]:[...prev.[propertyName],id]}))
}
```

On click

```
const handleClick=(someId)=>{
    commonUpdateFunction(someId,deleteArr)
}
```